# Postgres "on conflict...do update" is failing with UniqueContraint violation

Tags: postgresql, constraints, primary-key, upsert, postgresql-10

I want to implement upsert here. The values in some columns are going to be updated at every insert.

I am using -

```
insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp','not-active')  
on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey 
   DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), agent='na', status='active';
```

Table is -

```
create table if not exists deployment.nodes (
   account varchar(40), 
   hostname varchar(100),
   latest timestamptz, 
   agent varchar(50),
   status varchar(50), 
   primary key(account,hostname,agent)
);
```

After two/three inserts i get -

```
devops=# insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp','not-active')  on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), agent='ne', status='active';
INSERT 0 1
devops=# insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp','not-active')  on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), agent='ne', status='active';
INSERT 0 1
devops=# insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp','not-active')  on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), agent='ne', status='active';
INSERT 0 1
devops=# insert into deployment.nodes values('sind','11', now(),'temp','not-active')  on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), agent='ne', status='active';
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "nodes_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (account, hostname, agent)=(sind, 11, ne) already exists.
```

Postgres Version -

```
devops=# SHOW server_version;
 server_version
----------------
 10.11
```

Any idea what's happening?

Answer (score -1):

This is normal behaviour.
The first insert inserts with agent temp.  The second insert attempt updates the first record to agent ne.  The third one inserts agent temp again in a new record and the fourth one tries to update temp to agent ne causing the conflict with the first one.

Best regards,
Bjarni

Answer (score -1):

Thanks @Bjarni for clearing that out.

The on-conflict-update is supposed to update the row causing the conflict. 
In my case, the conflict resolver itself had a conflict it seems.

I used the same primary key values in my "insert statement' as well as on "conflict statement" and that solved the issue.

```
insert into deployment.nodes 
values('sind','11', now(),'temp','not-active')  
on conflict on constraint nodes_pkey 
   DO UPDATE SET latest=now(), agent='temp', status='active';
```

Thanks!

Comment: You can avoid repeating the `'temp'` value by using `agent = excluded.agent` in the update part